# How to have latexdiff ignore specific line of text?

Tags: latexdiff

I have a certain piece of latex code that is giving me problems with compilation after I did a `latexdiff`.

```
...
\LTcapwidth=\textwidth
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
...
```

Gives me a diff file containing:

```
\DIFaddbegin \LTcapwidth\DIFadd{=\textwidth
}\DIFaddend \begin{landscape}
 ...
```

But upon compilation I get the errors: `! Missing number, treated as zero` and `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)` on that line.

**Question:** Is there a way to have latexdiff ignore a certain piece of text?
 (in this case I assume I would like to ignore `\LTcapwidth=\textwidth`.)

I played around with the [latexdiff option](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/support/latexdiff/doc/latexdiff-man.pdf) `--exclude-safecmd="LTcapwidth,textwidth"` but that didn't really help as the equal sign between both commands is still diff'ed (i.e., I get `\DIFaddbegin \LTcapwidth\DIFadd{=}\textwidth\DIFaddend \begin{landscape}`)

Comment: Have you tried using *LaTeX* syntax for this command: `\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\textwidth}`.  latexdiff does not guarantee to work on plain tex syntax.

Comment: While this does resolve the problem (thanks!), I am looking for a solution that does not require me to change the latex file (multiple people working on it, svn repo, etc.).